# Scrapy: pip Install scrapy on windows 10 with python 3.6 and met Missing MSVCP140.dll file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

When I install scrapy framework on PC I met the error "command 'cl.exe' failed no such file or directory" and after I fixed it by importing path of cl.exe in visual studio 14 and I won't see that error again (command 'cl.exe' failed no such file or directory) but I met a new error that talking about file MSVCP140.dll is missing.

[image: file missing MSVCP140.dll]

Comment: Note that the current recommended way to install Scrapy on Windows is to [use Anaconda/Miniconda](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows) with the `conda-forge` channel.

Answer (score 3):

Installation of `Scrapy` on Windows may facing error while installing `Twisted`.Use `conda` is a easy way to deal with it.

**But if you want to use `pip` just following these step:**

1. Download `Twisted` according to your Python and windows version on this site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted
2. Turn to your download folder and `pip install <downloaded filename>`
3. `pip install scrapy`